# How to markup navigation within a footer using HTML5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a global navigation for my site which is in the header of all pages. I have marked it up using the `<nav>` tag.

I also have a navigation present on many individual pages that only apply to that page. So if its a long article, the page navigation lets you paginate sections. This too has been marked up using the `<nav>` tag.

All pages also have a footer which is almost identical to one at the bottom of StackOverflow's page. There are headings to group navigation links together, some copyright information, and anything else that's interesting.

I don't think its appropriate to also markup the footer's navigation within a `<nav>` tag because its not intended to be the main navigation for the page or any page. SO have used a table with `<th>` tags to wrap the headings (and the links are rows underneath) e.g:

```
<tr>
<th> TECHNOLOGY </th>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <ol>
  <li>Stack Overflow</li>
  <li>Server Fault</li>
  <li>Super User</li>
  </ol>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

With HTML5, I understand that description lists `<dl>` can be used for name-value pairs. So would the following be allowed/appropriate:

```
<dl>
<dt> TECHNOLOGY </dt>
<dd> Stack Overflow </dd>
<dd> Server Fault </dd>
<dd> Super User </dd>
</dl>
```

I can't think of a better way of doing it personally (without using nav + lists), but I also don't want to markup stuff incorrectly (i.e. causing poor semantic value).

If a HTML5 expert could shed some light that would be great.

UPDATE: I've had to make a judgement call and decided that a definition list is still the most semantically appropriate thing to use. Its just my personal judgement because just using a list is meaningless.

Comment: Just use a standard list element. Tables are probably the worst approach you could take.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official HTML 5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) on the `<nav>` element (emphasis by me):

> Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element — the
>   element is primarily intended for sections that consist of major
>   navigation blocks. In particular, it is common for footers to have a
>   short list of links to various pages of a site, such as the terms of
>   service, the home page, and a copyright page. **The footer element alone
>   is sufficient for such cases; while a nav element can be used in such
>   cases, it is usually unnecessary.**

I think using a `<dl>` in your case would not be semantically correct, since that element is reserved for association lists, pairing a name/term and a value.

You said it yourself that the footer menu you have is almost identical to Stack Overflow, so if you inspect the code of their menu it is constructed with an ordered list (`<ol>`).

Personally, I like to use unordered lists for navigation in most cases, and to get a header in your nav, I would suggest a construct like this:

```
<ul id="footer-menu">
   <li>
     <strong>TECHNOLOGY</strong>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="the-link.html">Stack Overflow</a></li>
        <li><a href="the-next-link.html">Server Fault</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In this way, each list-item of the "footer-menu" list can be a menu with a heading. Semantically, it is a list of link lists. I made a super-basic fiddle for you to illustrate how it would work: http://jsfiddle.net/psnb6tb9/

Comment: But a list of items does not semantically help to explain what that list's purpose is. The list's purpose is navigation, but not main navigation. Its kind of like a "you may also be interested in..." section that resides in the footer. And its the same information on every page because its in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to decide if you want to use heading elements (and sectioning content elements), or not. Both ways are possible. It mostly depends on whether you want the footer content to become part of the [document outline](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#outlines).

If yes, your `footer` would contain a `section` (possibly multiple, depending on your footer content), with several `section` as children, e.g.:

```html
<footer>
  <section>
    <!-- you may use a heading element here, e.g., 
    <h1>Sister sites</h1>
    -->

    <section>
      <h1>Technology</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Stack Overflow</li>
        <li>Server Fault</li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section>
      <h1>Life / Arts</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Science Fiction & Fantasy</li>
      </ul>
    </section>

  </section>
</footer>
```

This might especially make sense if the list of sister sites is complex/long, and relevant for your users.

If not, your `footer` would not contain any heading or sectioning content elements. The [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) seems to be appropriate in this case, e.g.:

```html
<footer>
  <dl>
    <dt>Technology</dt>
      <dd>Stack Overflow</dd>
      <dd>Server Fault</dd>
    <dt>Life / Arts</dt>
      <dd>Photography</dd>
      <dd>Science Fiction & Fantasy</dd>
  </dl>
</footer>
```

This might especially make sense if the list of sister sites is not really relevant or important for most of your users (I’d guess Stack Exchange’s footer falls into this category).
However, this is not really suitable if your footer would contain additional "sections" (in which case you probably should use sectioning content elements, i.e., `section`).

A middle ground would be to use a section/heading only for the whole list of sister sites, not for its sub-sections, e.g.:

```html
<footer>
  <section>
    <h1>Sister sites</h1>
      <dl>
        <dt>Technology</dt>
          <dd>Stack Overflow</dd>
          <dd>Server Fault</dd>
        <dt>Life / Arts</dt>
          <dd>Photography</dd>
          <dd>Science Fiction & Fantasy</dd>
      </dl>
  </section>
</footer>
```

This might especially make sense if the sister site list is relevant, but the categorization of these sister sites is not that important.

Comment: I was confused as to whether the dd elements had to describe WHAT the dt element is, or, whether its also okay for them to describe whats IN each dt